# get userFriendly names of dimmension attributes in mdx

Tags: c#, ssas, mdx, olap, mdxclient

I'm using the MDXClient library in my C# application. I browse cube and generate some reports based on mdx queries.

When I use Management Studio I have nice (user friendly) column names in the query result, but when I use this library the column names are very long and differ from what I have in Management Studio.

Sample query:

```
SELECT [My Question].[My Question].[My Question].AllMembers ON COLUMNS from [demo]
```

Sample result in management studio is one column:

[nice]

Sample result in my C# app is one column:

[My Question].[My Question].&curr_nice

How can i retrieve the same answer as what I see in SSMS?

Comment: What do you mean by "MDXClient library"? The classes in the Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient namespace? With which method do you execute your MDX statement?

Answer (score 0):

You are being presented with the full member name including which dimensions and levels it resides within.

I suspect your C# code has access to several member properties. Are you just asking for the default property? I cannot see the library documentation but I expect there is a `.Name` string property and a `.FormattedName` or some such alternative; maybe `.MemberName` ?

Or perhaps the name information is presented as an object, and you need to break it down into the constituent parts.